# How can I get {...rest} like this redux form's Deep form tutorial in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-form

In the [tutorial](http://redux-form.com/5.3.1/#/examples/deep?_k=us407w) I see this

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'

class PureInput extends Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return this.props.field !== nextProps.field
  }

  render() {
    const { field, ...rest } = this.props
    return <input {...field} {...rest}/>
  }
}

PureInput.propTypes = {
  field: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

export default PureInput
```

I have try as Typescript in my project like this

```
import * as React from 'react'

interface Props {
  field: any
}

export class PureInput extends React.Component<Props, void> {
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return this.props.field !== nextProps.field
  }

  render() {
    const { field, ...rest } = this.props
    return (<input {...field} {...rest} />)
  }
}
```

And it warn an errors on ...rest so what should I do ?, not sure that I should make the Props interface to dictionary by add code like [rest:string]:any into it or not, I have tried and it is not work

Comment: Typescript won't have that feature until version 2.1 https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap. for now just pass the props object, or filter the keys / values manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> const { field, ...rest } = this.props
> ```

This isn't support yet.

## More

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2103

Follow along for updates